# display case list including child account from parent account detail page

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting

im trying to get the list of all cases for current account record and also its child account cases. and display as a related list in account detail page.

is there any option with reporting or visual force pages ? any examples of VF pages would be appreciated.

i already set up a formula field in case object to store parent account id which might be used to query and list all the cases.

any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post [here](http://starrforce.com/2012/11/salesforce-reporting-on-related-records-by-parent-account/) suggests one way of accomplishing this through reports.

Comment: is it possible to use this for displaying cases ?

Comment: I believe so it says, "The text formula we developed allows reporting on Contacts, Cases, Opportunities, (or other objects related to accounts) for the whole hierarchy."

Comment: I will give it a shot too tonight (lunch break over), let me know if you get stuck.